# C Program- How do you find the index of any character in a string?

Tags: arrays, c, string

For example, in a string, you'll be asked to find and print the index of a capital character:

```
char str[100] = "helloWorld";
```

the capital letter is found at index `5` so `printf("Index of capital letter: Index %d")` in which `%d` should be `5`

How do you create a code to print the index?

Comment: `'helloWorld'` isn't a string, `"helloWorld"` is.

Comment: Create a loop which iterates over the string, and checks if [`isupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isupper) returns non-zero for the current character?

Answer (score 1):

To locate the first uppercase letter in the string, you must use a loop:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[100] = "helloWorld";
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (isupper((unsigned char)str[i]) {
            printf("Index of capital letter '%c': %d\n", str[i], i);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("No capital letter\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strcspn()`](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.5.3):

> **Synopsis**
>
> 1
>
> ```
>     #include <string.h>
>     size_t strcspn(const char *s1, const char *s2);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> 2 The `strcspn` function computes the length of the maximum initial
> segment of the string pointed to by `s1` which consists entirely of
> characters not from the string pointed to by `s2`.
>
> **Returns**
>
> 3 The strcspn function returns the length of the segment.

For example:

```
// get the index of the first upper-case character
// return ( ssize_t ) -1 if there are none
ssize_t firstUpperCase( const char *str )
{
    ssize_t index = strcspn( str, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" );
    if ( index >= strlen( str )
    {
        index = ( ssize_t ) -1;
    }
    return( index );
}
```